# passing any control as parameter in vb.net function

Tags: vb.net, function, parameters, controls

I have a following vb.net function as below in which i am passing a checkbox control name as parameter.Code is here

```
Public Function emaildata(ByVal grdv As GridView, ByVal ctrl As String, ByVal celpos As Integer) As GridView
        Dim comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        Dim bpv As String = ""
        Dim gv As New GridView
        For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In grdv.Rows
            Dim chkbx As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl(ctrl), CheckBox)
            If chkbx.Checked Then
                If bpv <> "" Then
                    bpv += ","
                End If
                bpv += gvrow.Cells(celpos).Text
                comm.CommandText = "SELECT chq_num Cheque#,to_char(bpv_amt,'9,999,999,999') Amount,vch_nar Narration,bnf_nam PartyName,acc_des Bank from  CHECK_DATA where bpv_num in(" & bpv.ToString() & ") and BPV_DTE=to_date('" & TreeView2.SelectedValue & "')"
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                comm.Connection = con
                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(comm)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)
                gv.DataSource = ds
                gv.DataBind()
            End If
        Next
        Return gv
    End Function
```

Problem is that i have to use same function with radiobutton also with text box and i don't want to write separate function for all type of controls.I want to detect the control as parameter and.For Example if i pass text box then function should behave like a text box and if radio then radion behaviour and if checkbox then same behaviour for this.I have these three control to pass the function and i want make a automatic detection method for these controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send ctrl as CONTROL(its a base class for all controls) as parameter.

You need to use latebinding and need to write separate cases for each control type....

Below code will work for checkbox only

```
Dim chkbx As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl(ctrl), CheckBox)
If chkbx.Checked Then
```

For textbox and radiobutton you need write additional code

```
Public Function emaildata(ByVal grdv As GridView, ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal celpos As Integer) As GridView

 If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then

 ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then 

 Else

 EndIf
```

Comment: Sir I am Asking about Additional Code will u please show some sample code for which i posted question

Comment: can i make i check with if condition that is passig control is text or radio or check then i will do something

Comment: First check which type of control then you can continue with next lines(Code).

Comment: then how can i manage this line for passing control name as string `Dim chkbx As CheckBox = CType(gvrow.FindControl(ctrl), CheckBox)`